# onaudioprocess not fired in an HTML5 voice recorder

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm building an HTML5 voice recording with a visualizer, but the program when running keeps giving me an error in the onaudioprocess that the variables are not declared this is because the onaudioprocess is not running.what is going wrong???here is my full code:

```
// variables
var leftchannel = [];
var rightchannel = [];
var recorder = null;
var recording = false;
var recordingLength = 0;
var volume = null;
var audioInput = null;
var sampleRate = 44100;
var audioContext = null;
var context = null;
var outputString;


if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia){
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, success, function(e) {
alert('Error capturing audio.');
});
} else alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');



function getVal(value)
  {


if ( value == "record"){
    recording = true;
    // reset the buffers for the new recording
    leftchannel.length = rightchannel.length = 0;
    recordingLength = 0;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML="Recording now...";


} else if ( value == "stop" ){

    // we stop recording
    recording = false;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML="Building wav file...";

    // we flat the left and right channels down
    var leftBuffer = mergeBuffers ( leftchannel, recordingLength );
    var rightBuffer = mergeBuffers ( rightchannel, recordingLength );
    // we interleave both channels together
    var interleaved = interleave ( leftBuffer, rightBuffer );



    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + interleaved.length * 2);
    var view = new DataView(buffer);

    // RIFF chunk descriptor
    writeUTFBytes(view, 0, 'RIFF');
    view.setUint32(4, 44 + interleaved.length * 2, true);
    writeUTFBytes(view, 8, 'WAVE');
    // FMT sub-chunk
    writeUTFBytes(view, 12, 'fmt ');
    view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
    view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
    // stereo (2 channels)
    view.setUint16(22, 2, true);
    view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
    view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
    view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
    view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
    // data sub-chunk
    writeUTFBytes(view, 36, 'data');
    view.setUint32(40, interleaved.length * 2, true);


    var lng = interleaved.length;
    var index = 44;
    var volume = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++){
        view.setInt16(index, interleaved[i] * (0x7FFF * volume), true);
        index += 2;
    }

    var blob = new Blob ( [ view ], { type : 'audio/wav' } );

    // let's save it locally

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML='Handing off the file now...';
    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var hf = document.createElement('a');

    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;
    hf.href = url;
    hf.download = 'audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.wav';
    hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
    li.appendChild(au);
    li.appendChild(hf);
    recordingList.appendChild(li);

}
}


function success(e){

audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
context = new audioContext();


volume = context.createGain();

// creates an audio node from the microphone incoming stream(source)
source = context.createMediaStreamSource(e);

// connect the stream(source) to the gain node
source.connect(volume);

var bufferSize = 2048;

recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 2, 2);

//node for the visualizer
analyser = context.createAnalyser();
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
analyser.fftSize = 1024;

analyser2 = context.createAnalyser();
analyser2.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.0;
analyser2.fftSize = 1024;


splitter = context.createChannelSplitter();
//when recording happens
recorder.onaudioprocess = function(e){

    if (!recording) return;
    var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData (0);
    var right = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData (1);

    // get the average of the first channel, bincount is fftsize / 2
    var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
    var average = getAverageVolume(array);

     // get the average for the second channel
    var array2 =  new Uint8Array(analyser2.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser2.getByteFrequencyData(array2);
    var average2 = getAverageVolume(array2);
    // clear the current state
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 60, 130);

    // set the fill style
    context.fillStyle=gradient;

    // create the meters
    context.fillRect(0,130-average,25,130);
    context.fillRect(30,130-average2,25,130);
}

function getAverageVolume(array) {
    var values = 0;
    var average;

    var length = array.length;

    // get all the frequency amplitudes
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        values += array[i];
    }

    average = values / length;
    return average;
    }

    leftchannel.push (new Float32Array (left));
    rightchannel.push (new Float32Array (right));
    recordingLength += bufferSize;

    // we connect the recorder(node to destination(speakers))
    volume.connect(splitter);
    splitter.connect(analyser, 0, 0);
    splitter.connect(analyser2, 1, 0);
    analyser.connect(recorder);
    recorder.connect(context.destination);

}




function mergeBuffers(channelBuffer, recordingLength){
var result = new Float32Array(recordingLength);
var offset = 0;
var lng = channelBuffer.length;
for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++){
var buffer = channelBuffer[i];
result.set(buffer, offset);
offset += buffer.length;
}
    return result;
   }

function interleave(leftChannel, rightChannel){
var length = leftChannel.length + rightChannel.length;
var result = new Float32Array(length);

var inputIndex = 0;

for (var index = 0; index < length; ){
result[index++] = leftChannel[inputIndex];
result[index++] = rightChannel[inputIndex];
inputIndex++;
}
return result;
}


function writeUTFBytes(view, offset, string){ 
var lng = string.length;
for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++){

 view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
}
}
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, pushing the left and right channel should be within the onaudioprocess

```
  leftchannel.push (new Float32Array (left));
  rightchannel.push (new Float32Array (right));
  recordingLength += bufferSize;
```